# Retrieve multiple ResultSets without using StoredProcedures

Tags: java, sql, db2, sql-optimization

Is there a way in Java 1.5 to retrieve multiple `ResultSet` objects from a DB2 database with a single SQL call without resorting to StoredProcedures / `CallableStatements`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. I don't think it is possible to get multiple ResultSet objects in single SQL call. You may refer [JDBC API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html).

Comment: Damn - I was hoping there would be some esoteric magic code :( oh well, thanks anyway!

Comment: Unfortunately no. Enjoy coding.